# Error in data type being received over socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a server and a client set up in Python and I am attempting to return a confirmation message from the server to the client but, despite casting the message (server side) as a string, it is being printed on the client as a bool (coming through as `FALSE`).

Sending of the confirmation message (server):

```
helomessage = str("HELO")
helomessage_send = helomessage.encode('utf-8')
helomessage_header = f"{len(helomessage_send):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
print("Sending: ", helomessage_send)
client_socket.send(helomessage_header + helomessage_send)
```

Receiving of the confirmation message (client):

```
hellomessage_encoded = receive_message(client_socket)
print(helomessage_encoded)
helomessage = format(helomessage_encoded['data'].decode('utf-8'))
print(helomessage)
```

With `'receive_message'` being the following function on the client:

```
def receive_message(client_socket):

try:
    message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
    if not len(message_header):
        return False
    message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
    return {'header': message_header, 'data': client_socket.recv(message_length)}
except:
    return False
```

Upon running this, the received value (that prints on `print(helomessage_encoded)`) comes up as `'False'`.

How do I fix this so the client receives the intended string?

Comment: Your exception handling is worse than useless, it's plain harmful - you just silent __any__ error message and return `False`, and as a result you don't know what failed. Remove this exception handler completely, and you'll have the error message and full traceback.

Comment: Correct exception handling primer: 1/ never EVER use a bare except clause, always specify the exact error(s) you expect at a given point. 2/ only catch errors that you can actually handle at this point (nb; returning an error message to a client app is one possible way to handle an error), else let them propagate upper the call stack. 3. if your app is a long running process (server or whatever), add a catchall exception handler at the top level that at least logs the error (with the full traceback, cf `logging.exception()`) and returns an error message one way or another

Comment: Oh and yes: except possibly for a top-level catchall handler, put as few code as possible in your try block, and if you're not 110% sure you know _exactly_ why this exception occurred, log it with the full traceback (an example of where you can be 110% sure of the issue would be a KeyError when looking up a dict - assuming the dict lookup is the only statement in your try block).

Answer (score 0):

where your compare? I am giving a example you can compare anything to do like <=, >= <, > and more

```
...
    if not len(message_header) > 0:
        return False
...
```